# Why am I getting an undefined symbol error on execution for a program built with Android NDK?

Tags: android-ndk

I am building jack2 sound server for my Android 10 phone using Android NDK.
For assembly, I also use these header files https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/native/+/refs/heads/android10-release/libs/binder/include/binder
For linking I use libbinder.so from my phone.
Compilation and linking is successful. As a result, I get the libjackshm.so library containing the symbol

```
nm libjackshm.so | grep IInterfaceE | grep U
                 U _ZTIN7android10IInterfaceE
```

The IInterface class is declared in the header file as virtual.
The libbinder.so library contains the following symbols for this class:

```
nm -D libbinder.so | grep android10IInterfaceE
0000000000090778 D _ZTTN7android10IInterfaceE
00000000000906e0 D _ZTVN7android10IInterfaceE
```

As you can see, this symbol does not exist, and therefore, when executed, I receive the error "undefined symbol"

What to do? Help me please.

If I use the linker flag -Wl, -no-undefined, then I get the error

```
ld: error: undefined symbol: typeinfo for android :: IInterface
>>> referenced by BnAndroidShm.cpp
>>> /tmp/BnAndroidShm-00b005.o:(construction vtable for android :: IInterface-in-android :: BnAndroidShm)
>>> referenced by BnAndroidShm.cpp
>>> /tmp/BnAndroidShm-00b005.o:(construction vtable for android :: IInterface-in-android :: BnAndroidShm)
>>> referenced by BpAndroidShm.cpp
>>> /tmp/BpAndroidShm-28ca44.o:(construction vtable for android :: IInterface-in-android :: BpAndroidShm)
>>> referenced 6 more times
>>> did you mean: VTT for android :: IInterface
>>> defined in: build / vendorlibs / libbinder.so
```

Answer (score 1):

Using -fno-rtti clang++ flag solve my problem.